# How to call "somename.html" from a method in a .gs file by passing a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am creating a web-app, in which it has some validation before it successfully loads the "searchByDocumentPage.html" by passing a parameter.

In my previous code, I called the `doGet()` method directly using `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` so other buttons do not have any issue in loading new HTML page.

Since I do some validation, for some reason I can't load the "searchByDocumentPage.html" HTML Page.

1st I tried:

```
var html = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?v=submitDocumentID";
return html;
```

2nd:

```
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("searchByDocumentPage").evaluate();
```

```
if(fileID === ""){
  document.getElementById("errorMessageDiv").innerHTML='<label style="color:red;text-align:center;font-style: italic;font-size: 12px;">Please key in the Document ID</label>';
}
else{
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fnFileID).getFiles(fileID);
}

function fnFileID(returnedVal){
  if(returnedVal === "No File"){
    document.getElementById("errorMessageDiv").innerHTML='<label style="color:red;text-align:center;font-style: italic;font-size: 12px;">This Document ID do not exist</label>';
  }
  /*else{
    ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?v=submitDocumentID";
  }*/
}
```

```
function getFiles(fileID) {
  var returnValue = "";
  var arrayTblFile = [];
  var selectStatementTblFile = "SELECT File_ID FROM webapp_tblFile WHERE File_ID='" + fileID  +"'";
  arrayTblFile= MySQLSelectQuery(selectStatementTblFile);//Call the SQL 
}

function from MySQLConnection.gs
  if(arrayTblFile.length == 0){
    returnValue = "No File";
  }
  else{    
    loadSearchByDocPage(fileID);
  }
  return returnValue;
}

function loadSearchByDocPage(fileID){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("searchByDocumentPage").evaluate();

  //var html = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?v=submitDocumentID";
  //return html;
}

function doGet(e){
  var params = e.parameter;
  if(params.v === 'newDoc'){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("newDocumentPage");
  }
  else if(params.v === 'submitDocumentID'){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("searchByDocumentPage").evaluate();
  }
  else{
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("landingPage").evaluate();
  }
}
```

Expected to load "searchByDocumentPage.html" by passing parameter.

Comment: You say `Expected to load "searchByDocumentPage.html" by passing parameter.`, what is it you're receiving if not the page?

Comment: Either the example above is missing some code or your 'getFiles()' function doesn't actually return a value to be passed to the success handler.

Comment: @ Rafa Guillermo = What am i receiving now:- Its not doing any action. Its not redirecting to the "searchByDocumentPage.html". It just stays in the current page without any action. I do not know how to trigger the doGet() or return the HtmlService directly.

Comment: @ Anton Dementiev = Yes you are right, i didn't include the parameter code. It should be like this:- var html = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()+"?v=submitDocumentID&id="+fileID;
return html; But before i pass parameter, at least I would like to see the page "searchByDocumentPage.html" get loaded.

Comment: If i call the ScriptApp straight after pressing button, the page loading perfectly fine. Now that I am doing some validation first, i am not sure how do I redirect to the "searchByDocumentPage.html" page after the validation is done

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best practice, but I managed to load the page only. I am still  unsure how to pass the parameter.

     $("#btnSubmit_DocumentID").append(
            '<a id="loadSearchByDoc" href="<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); ?>?v=submitDocumentID"></a>'
                   
      );
       document.getElementById('loadSearchByDoc').click();

function doGet(e){
  if(params.v === 'submitDocumentID'){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("searchByDocumentPage").evaluate();
  }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is best practice, I have done the following and managed to get what i intended to see.

1. Append with hyperlink and included the parameter in the link
2. Trigger the hyperlink
3. doGet() triggered and the page loaded successfully with the parameter

```js
function fnFileID(returnedVal){
   $("#btnSubmit_DocumentID").append(
        '<a id="loadSearchByDoc" href="<?= ScriptApp.getService().getUrl(); ?>?v=submitDocumentID&fileID=' + returnedVal + '"></a>'
    );
   document.getElementById('loadSearchByDoc').click(); 
}
```

```
`function doGet(e){
  if(params.v === 'submitDocumentID'){
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("searchByDocumentPage").evaluate();

   }
 }
 `
```